# xmgrace: changing color of the XY graph in batch execution

Tags: bash, gnuplot, xmgrace

I am using gracebat integrated into my bash script to make simple XY graph from 2D numerical data

```
gracebat input.xvg -hdevice PNG -fixed 800 600 -world 0 0.02 610 0.5 -printfile output.png -hardcopy
```

This simple execution without GUI produces the XY graph totally in black color!
[image]
would it be possible to quickly change to color of the line (I guess should be s0 color in the batch file) without using batch file for gracebat: e.g. via some option of gracebat or alternatively via editing of the input.xvg (via sed or any shell utility) specifying color or the line:

```
@ s0 line color 2
```

Alternatively, if the grace has not good possibilities for graph customization, I would be grateful for simple example of the gnuplot batch execution.

Comment: So, you are asking for a xmgrace and/or gnuplot command line for plotting data from a file with a red line. What have you tried? Have you checked the manuals (RT*M)? In gnuplot have you checked `help command line options`? Please show some own research effort. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: actually the question was mainly related to xmgrace since it's easy to execute it from batch for such simple tasks. however, if it's not possible to change the graph color w/o GUI I would definetely try the Gnuplot for such graph. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does `xmgrace -help` say? Please check the corresponding manuals and homepages and do a search on SO and the web *before* asking such questions. I don't now xmgrace and its documentation.

But a gnuplot command line would be using the command line option `-e`: (check `help command line options`).

```
gnuplot -e "set term pngcairo size 800,600; set output 'myFile.png'; plot 'myFile.dat' u 1:2 w l lc 'red' "
```

Comment: great! thank you very much! just a few question related to gnuplot : how to disable legend on the graph (it plots now the name and full path of the input xvg directly on the graph) ? how would it be possible to increase the thickness of the produced color line ?

Comment: Great, I gotcha thank you very much! Actually this is one of my first experience with gnuplot but I will use it now instead of xmgrace. It's so cool!

Comment: probably just one minor question about using bash variables inside your gnuplot script. E.g. I added there ; set title 'RMSF of ${simulation}'; where simulation is the name of the xvg. It prints correctly the name of the file but the format is alitle bit strange e.g. it scips  the "_" characters from the file name

Comment: @JamesStarlight ok, as a beginner there are a lot of pitfalls and unknowns. You probably have to set `set title ... noenhanced` or maybe `set termoption noenhanced`. In enhanced text mode `_` is used for subscript. Check `help enhanced`. Basically for every command there is a help entry. Please always check ` help <keyword>`  and read it carefully **before** asking. In your case this would have been `help title`.